# Undoing text-decoration uppercase on WordPress titles (Twentyfourteen theme)

Tags: css, wordpress

I use a customized theme ,it is twentyfourteen-child.
All the title in wordpress will change into uppercase by default.
I add a  css in /var/www/html/wp/wp-content/themes/twentyfourteen-child/style.css.

```
h1.entry-title {
    text-transform: none !important;
}
```

It take no effect at all!

cat  /var/www/html/wp/wp-content/themes/twentyfourteen-child/style.css

```
*{
    font-family:"DejaVu Sans Mono" !important;
}
.site {
    max-width: 1920px;
}
.site::before{
    width:400px;
}
.site-header {
    max-width: 1920px;
}

.site-content header .entry-meta {
    max-width: 100%;
}
.site-content .entry-header,
.site-content .entry-content,
.site-content .entry-summary,
.site-content .entry-meta,
.site-content .navigation,
.comments-area,
.page-header,
.page-content {
    max-width: 70%;
}

article{
    margin-bottom:10px;
}

#secondary ul li{
    color:black;
    width:360px;
    font-size:16px;
}

.entry-meta  .cat-links{
    display:none;
}

pre{
    font-family:inherit;
    font-size:16px;
    border:1px solid red;
}


h1.entry-title {
    text-transform: none !important;
}
```

My `twentyfourteen-child` theme activated.
[image]

To check a title with inspect.
[image]

Why the element `h1.entry-title` was not decorated by `http://hwy.local/wp/wp_content/themes/twentyfourteen/style.css?ver=4.9.8:1112`,
instead of  `/var/www/html/wp/wp-content/themes/twentyfourteen-child/style.css` ?

Comment: And the theme is activated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To clear all cache in my browser,twentyfourteen-child theme take effect.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
.entry-title {text-transform: none!important;}
```

... or simply:

```
h1.entry-title {text-transform: none;}
```

Both solutions win the specificity battle (as does your code). You probably did not load the CSS correctly. Right click the entry-title and see if it is applied and/or overwritten.